# how to create a function in MySQL5?

Tags: mysql

The question is  what's happening?

```
CREATE FUNCTION HiWorld() RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
BEGIN
RETURN 'Hi';
END;
```

RESULT: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION hiworld()
RETURNS VARCHAR(20) DETERMINISTIC
begin
return 'Hello';
end//
delimiter ;

Comment: May you tell me how i can to DECLARE A Variable into a procedure?

Comment: Ugh sorry it's been forever...sometimes i'm a slug.
Declare vars the same way you would create columns in a table.

  DECLARE somevar INT default 0;
  SET somevar = 12;

  # more useful...
  SELECT count(*) INTO somevar FROM SomeTable;